# Как меняется подход к программированию, если планируется 50 000 уников в день?

Tags: php, вконтакте, codeigniter, mysql

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос.
Раньше я всегда писал обычные сайты на Code Igniter, до 100 уников в день, поэтому не заморачивался со скоростью загрузки, настройкой сервера и прочие штуки, поэтому в этом вопросе очень мало компетенции.

Как меняется подход к программированию, если планируется 50 000 уников в день? 
Понятно что кеширование, какое лучше подойдёт? 
Какая база данных лучше, MySQL с 30 таблицами справиться? 
Нужен ли выделенный сервер, какая ОСь и сервер лучше подойдёт?
Меняется ли как-то стиль написания кода, как? 
Нужно ли использовать фреймворки, имею ввиду CodeIgniter, или лучше с нуля самому писать?

Что ещё посоветуете при написании проектов с высокой нагруженностью?

Как я понял Вконтакте тоже написан на PHP, как им удаётся справляться с такой нагрузкой?

Заранее всем спасибо большое за ваши компетентные ответы.

Comment: > Нужно ли использовать фреймворки, имею ввиду CodeIgniter, или лучше с нуля самому писать?

Лучше с нуля самом **не писать**, лучше не использовать CodeIgniter.

> Что ещё посоветуете при написании проектов с высокой нагруженностью?

ознакомиться с нотацией Big O, поставить и использовать [athletic](https://github.com/polyfractal/athletic), откопать и прочитать всю информацию про тестирование, которая найдется.

> Нужен ли выделенный сервер,

да

> какая ОСь и сервер лучше подойдёт?

любая / nginx + php-fpm давно стал "джентельменским выбором"

Comment: Ну, вообще-то highload - это очень многосторонний вопрос, и только фреймворком тут ограничиться не выйдет. Хотя, конечно, писать с нуля тоже не вариант, если задаются вопросы такого уровня :) Попробуйте посмотреть про самые азы ([например][1]), а направления куда копать дальше сами всплывут. Пока слишком много вопросов "обо всём" получается.


  [1]: http://www.phphighload.com/

Comment: > Как я понял Вконтакте тоже написан на PHP, как им удаётся справляться с такой нагрузкой?

Много серверов + функциональное программирование + половина вообще написана на сишке, которая в десятке самых скорострельных языков + собственный компилятор PHP в байткод ([kphp](https://github.com/vk-com/kphp-kdb))

> Понятно что кеширование, какое лучше подойдёт?

конкретный движок зависит от задач и предпочтений, а так, понятное дело, в оперативку

> Какая база данных лучше, MySQL с 30 таблицами справиться? 

**справится**, без мягкого знака. Опять зависит от многих факторов, но в первую очередь ->

Comment: надо решить, нужен SQL или NoSQL движок. Дальше при правильном написании кода можно будет *относительно* безболезненно поменять движок на соседний.

> Меняется ли как-то стиль написания кода, как?

Нельзя писать кривой, недокументированный, неотформатированный код, потом это сильно аукается. Следовать PSR, оставлять везде PHPDoc комментарии, по-максимуму изолировать модули друг от друга, следовать SOLID.

Answer (score 4):

Спустя два года после некоторого (но не сказать, что совсем большого) опыта бодания с проблемой больших нагрузок могу дать немного более развернутый ответ.

Первое, что необходимо принять при переходе на территорию сервисов, заточенных под нагрузки - это то, что предыдущие правила больше не действуют. И, зачастую, были в корне неверны. Например, больше нет такой штуки, как JOIN (некоторые хранилища, о которых поговорим далее, их поддерживают, но из-за физической невозможности сделать их правильно это является очередным способом прострелить ногу), или то, что данные должны храниться в нормализованном виде, или что лог должен писаться в текстовый файл (туда - тоже, но только во вторую очередь), или что какие-то данные можно кэшировать в памяти. Это все прекрасно работает в рамках модели одного сервера, но безудержно разваливается при переходе к масштабируемой системе, а потом оказывается, что этот подход и вовсе не был нужен. И, наконец, оказывается, что общепринятых решений задач и вовсе нет.

В первую очередь нагрузки упираются в то, что один сервер физически не может выдержать то, что к нему приходит. Либо это просто файловая система (e.g. вы строите фотохостинг - у вас просто физически не получится выделить отдельный сервер под статику, потому что он скоро закончится), либо это оперативка (e.g. не хватает места под быстрый кэш), либо это процессор (слишком сложные вопросы к базе данных, слишком много одновременно обрабатываемых запросов), или, если вы написали идеальное приложение, у вас тупо не хватает пропускной мощности сетевого порта. При возникновении любой из этих проблем встает необходимость горизонтального масштабирования - масштабирования за счет роста парка серверов, и этот фактор и обуславливает большинство возникающих проблем, потому что работать старыми способами больше не получится.

### БД

Самое первое, что всегда выскакивает в таких обсужедниях - это база данных. Базу данных действительно довольно легко нагрузить сложным запросом, и тогда она начнет тормозить запрос, тормозить соседние запросы и жрать проц; похожая ситуация произойдет и при наплыве пользователей. Поэтому базу данных надо **разнести на разные узлы**, **использовать оптимизированные запросы**, и, что вытекает из предыдущего пункта, **оптимизировать хранение данных**.

Про разнесение базы данных придется выделить отдельный параграф. При разделении любой системы на несколько узлов она становится распределенной, и это повышает ее сложности на порядок. Во-первых, каждый из узлов не может хранить все данные (потому что иначе сфера применения базы данных ограничивается размером дискового пространства одного сервера), во-вторых, каждый из узлов может внезапно умереть, а система при этом должна продолжать работать, как ни в чем не бывало. Против первой проблемы применяется так называемый **шардинг** - равномерное распределение данных по узлам. Как правило, это делается следующим образом: внутри кластера базы данных существует некоторое число *виртуальных узлов*, которые распределяются между участниками кластера, при прибытии новых участников или уходе старых виртуальные узлы перераспределяются между участниками. При добавлении записи в базу данных высчитывается хэш от ее partition key (partition key может как являться самим primary key, так и быт ьего частью - все зависит от выбранной базы данных), после чего при помощи математического преобразования из этого хэша вычисляется виртуальный узел, на котором должна располагаться эта запись - это математическое преобразование может быть простым `partition_key_hash % virutal_node_count` - и, наконец, на основе полученного виртуального узла производится запись в необходимый сервер БД.

Со второй проблемой - возможным выведением участников из кластера - борются простой репликацией данных. Запись обычно ведется не только в выбранный виртуальный узел, но и в N узлов за ним, и если участник внезапно выбывает из кластера, то зарегистрированные за ним виртуальные узлы восстанавливаются из репликаций.

На деле это все означает следующее:

- В системе **нет** единого места, где собрана вся таблица, и получение полного списка данных может вызвать затруднения
- В системе **нет** такого понятия, как джойн - джойн должен взять все данные из одной таблицы и сопоставить с данными другой таблицы, а таблицы, как уже было написано ранее, размазаны равномерным слоем по всему кластеру, и их получение (не говоря уж о том, что они могут физически превышать размер дисковой системы и оперативной памяти любого из узлов кластера) может в занять длительное время.
- Пропускная способность системы на получение записи по первичному ключу равняется средней пропускной способности одного узла * количество узлов, т.е., скажем, получение записей со скоростью гигабайт в секунд - вполне реальная ситуация. Netflix в свое время выбил из кассандры миллион записей в секунд на трех сотнях серверов (и это далеко не предел).
- Из-за асинхронности репликации для получения достоверных данных необходимо, чтобы коэффициент R (количество серверов, с которых производится чтение) + W (количество серверов, на которые производится запись) был больше или равен N + 1 (общее количество серверов + 1). На самом деле, доступности и целостности данных можно посвятить целую главу, и без этого **нельзя** работать с NoSQL, но я не смогу это все сейчас расписать. Начать стоит с теоремы CAP.
- В системе **нет** транзакций. Это теоретически возможно, но очень сложно и медленно.

Оптимизированные запросы, про которые я говорил, должны подстраиваться под конкретное хранилище. Большую часть головной боли убивает само отсутствие джойнов, и в остальном остается добавить только необходимость следить за тем, чтобы запросы всегда использовали индексы и не насиловали базу данных (не использовали джойны в тех хранилищах, которые все-таки дают возможность их использовать, не использовали специфические фичи, требующие чтения данных с диска и т.п.). Это накладывает определенные ограничения, и самые прозорливые (или просто знающие) уже поняли, что если просто использовать индексы на всех полях, то это это как раз-таки будет насилием над кластерам: из-за того, что все данные случайно-равномерно распределены по всем узлам , запрос "выдать пользователей 35 лет" уйдет на **все** узлы, а это излишняя нагрузка на базу данных (потому что можно было бы это рассчитать на одном узле. Поэтому этот подход обычно требует строить т.н. materialized views - отдельные таблицы, для которых эти выборки будут более простыми. Так, в cassandra можно построить отдельную таблицу, у которой partition key будет состоять только из возраста пользователя, и подобный поиск будет необходимо осуществлять только по ней - тогда будет использоваться только один узел БД. Отдельно отмечу, что последний пассаж про materialized views работает в указанном варианте в контексте cassandra, и у других хранилищ все может быть по-другому, но принцип остается таким же: для удобоваримой выборки можно сделать дополнительные таблицы, где хранить данные в удобном для выборок виде.

#### Поиск

Остается вопрос с поисковыми запросами. Поисковые запросы любят использовать много столбцов, и подготовить для них данные, как правило, не получится. Обычно в этом случае используют отдельный поисковый движок, например, elasticsearch, который по возможности размещается на жирном узле с большим количеством оперативки, в которой он хранит все индексы (иногда из-за объема данных это невозможно и все-таки приходится хранить индексы на диске). Там уже сложно добиться того, чтобы работал только один узел из кластера (но возможно), и вообще принципы работы становятся немного другими, но в этом случае подход к ресурсам, как правило, несколько более допустимый. В некоторых (критичных) случаях может потребоваться пойти на крайние меры и строить и хранить подобные штуки прямо в памяти внутри своего приложения, но это тоже обширная тема, в которой выстрелить в ногу проще простого; надо сказать только о том, что такая структура обязана быть неизменяемой, и надо проработать все возможные печальные варианты с распределением этой структуры по всем поисковым серверам (да-да, само написанное приложение тоже будет располагаться далеко не на одном сервере).

### Файловое хранилище

Про файловое хранилище можно только повторить @cheops - вам потребуется какая-то распределенная система, которая не будет капать вам на мозги кончающимся местом на дисках. Проще всего воспользоваться сторонним провайдером, благо их тьма тьмущая - S3, Swift и совместимые с ними производные.

### Кэширование

Вопрос с кэшированием данных, как известно, очень тонкий, и с ним надо быть очень осторожным. Тут можно дать несколько четких напутствий:

- Кэшировать данные можно **только** в отдельном стороннем сетевом сервисе, если не хотите ловить сложноуловимые баги.
- Сервис кэширования должен следовать тем же принципам, что и вышеописанные БД - должен легко и безболезненно шардироваться. Т.к. кэш представляет собой просто key-value хранилище, шардинг легко можно написать и самому, но вместо этого стоит взять просто нормальный сервис для кэширования. Мой личный фаворит - Aerospike.
- Нужно быть готовым к т.н. dogpile-эффекту, когда сотня (две, три, четырнадцать) юзеров приходит за одним и тем же ресурсом, а его нет в кэше. В этом случае есть вероятность пробить как базу данных, так и сотню (две, три, четырнадцать) раз перестроить кэш (вместо одного на каждый из серверов). С lazyload здесь надо быть очень осторожным.
- Помните про фразу об инвалидации данных. Словить проблему целостности данных (в базе обновилось, в кэше - нет) очень легко, найти причину - сложно.

### Приложение

#### Распределение нагрузки

Здесь, наконец-то, можно поговорить о самом приложении. Т.к. мы считаем, что один сервер не может принять всю нагрузку, мы начинаем разбрасывать одно и то же приложение по серверам и балансировать нагрузку. Тут начинаются выстрелы в ногу со стороны плохой архитектуры:

- Нельзя залить файлы на сервер, а затем ajax-запросом пробросить их дальше. ajax-запрос упадет не на тот сервер.
- Нельзя проверять что-то через наличие файла. Файла не будет, он на другом сервере.
- Нельзя ничего кэшировать на уроввне сервера. Этот кэш потом нельзя будет сбросить - он на другом сервере.

Поэтому нужно сразу писать т.н. stateless-приложения. Эти приложения не хранят никакого состояния в себе, а скидывают их в БД или кэш; в крайнем случае, указывают, к какому серверу относятся эти данные (например, чтобы в случае перезагрузки сервера он смог дозалить файлы, принятые от пользователя).

#### Микросервисы

Так или иначе приложение делится на отдельные домены (e.g. пользователи, подписки, поиск, основные записи, etc.), которые, потенциально, могут давить друг друга. Например, сервису подписок **нормально** занимать 100% процессора в течение пяти минут, а сервису пользователей, который пытается их логинить, это очень не нравится. В этом случае стоит начать делить нагрузку не только по серверам, но и по отдельным микроприложениям, которые будут общаться друг с другом. После этого подписки начинают жить на одном сервере, менеджер пользователей с поиском - на другом, перестают блокировать друг друга и живут красивой жизнью.

#### Язык программирования и внутрення архитектура

Нельзя все-таки не зацепиться и за эту проблему, которую по политическим мотивам обычно обходят стороной. На PHP всю эту махину поднять практически невозможно из-за отстуствия асинхронности: в случае, если надо будет получить данные по двадцати юзерам, PHP потратит на это в двадцать раз больше времени, чем стоило бы. В связи с тем, что количество микросервисов будет только увеличиваться, и каждый из них может немного протормозить, на синхронной модели это вообще практически невозможно вытянуть. Здесь нужна поддержка асинхронных вызовов, которая упирается в многопточность, которая, в конце концов, упирается и в архитектуру сервера (event loop и настоящая асинхронность будут качественнее утилизовать процессор, чем модель thread-per-request с блокирующими запросами к БД, но на самом деле не настолько, чтобы не использовать thread-per-request вообще). Я не могу порекомендовать конкретный язык (их много, мейнстримовые - все JVM-based, C#, NodeJS), но мой опыт (пусть и небольшой) говорит о том, что без этого не вытянуть вообще никак.

#### Парадигмы

Помните о том, что все те парадигмы, которые работали с вами до этого моменты - это рабочие, но не обязательно оптимальные парадигмы. Я недавно открыл для себя event sourcing, который является намного более сложным способом взаимодействия, чем CRUD, но в паре мест просто идеально подходит для моих задач и решит даже ту проблему, где я собирался сделать шардинг, о чем будет следующая секция.

#### Вопросы шардинга

Рано или поздно вам действительно может прийти в голову мысль о том, что внутри приложения по тем или иным причинам необходимо сделать шардинг своими руками. **Не делайте этого**. Вслед за шардингом рано или поздно скорее всего придет необходимость делать динамический решардинг, а это может обернуться настоящим адом в борьбе с race conditions. Оставьте это базе данных.

#### Логирование

Если логгер еще не был вашим лучшим другом, то теперь либо это наконец произойдет, либо проект не взлетит. Логировать каждый чих - это де-факто обязанность программиста, которая здесь становится еще сильнее в виду сложности распределенной системы, размазанной по кластеру серверов. Если что-то произошло, у вас перед глазами должна быть полная картина происходившего процесса, расписанная по шагам и оборванная исключением с полным стектрейсом. Иначе вы просто не сможете что-либо починить.
В виду того, что в случае проблем вы даже не узнаете, на каком узле произошла ошибка, логи нужно центарлизованно собирать. Обычно их отправляют в сборщик логов по стеи тем способом, который сборщик поддерживает; мы в проектах используем связку AMQP + Graylog.

#### Метрики

И, наконец, метрики. Как известно, то, чего не видно, может не работать, а вы этого можете не заметить. Поэтому обязательно собирайте в приложении все возможные метрики по его отзывчивости, проваленным задачам, подозрительным моментам - все, что вообще возможно собрать. Без этого вы не сможете оценить работоспособность приложения и выявить узкие точки или вообще определить, что фоновая задача отвалилась. Сами собранные метрики надо так или иначе выгружать в средства визуализации (graphite, influxdb), но здесь я не смогу подсказать что-то конкретное.

### Бесполезные вещи

Бесполезными вещами являются выбор конкретной ОС, тюнинг для повышения производительности на 25% и простые микрооптимизации в коде. Всё это - абсолютно бесполезные вещи до тех пор, пока компания не доросла до сотни человек, каждый из которых является специалистом. До этого момента ваше время пригодится в куче других мест, которые нужно будет латать куда быстрее. Сражаясь с нагрузками, вы сражаетесь с `O(n^x)`, и вам нужно в первую очередь работать с местами, в которых нашгрузка растет экспоненциально; все остальные места гораздо дешевле закрыть парой лишних серверов.